# Met "Check failure stack trace: " when running Caffe

Tags: python, stack, trace, caffe

I use python (The IDE is Pycharm) to run a net and a pretrained model to get 8 outputs. The code is like this:

```
myNet = root + netName
myModel = root + modelName
net = caffe.Net(myNet , myModel , caffe.TEST)
```

The net is really simple:

```
name: "Trial"
layer {
    name: "data"
    type: "MemoryData"
    top: "imgPairsSubMean"
    top: "boundings" 
    memory_data_param {
        batch_size: 1
        channels: 2
        height: 64
        width: 64
      }
    include {
        phase: TEST
    }
}

layer {
    name: "conv1"
    type: "Convolution"
    bottom: "imgPairsSubMean"
    top: "conv1"
    param {
        lr_mult: 1
    }
    param {
        lr_mult: 2
    }
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 1
        pad: 1
        kernel_size: 3
        stride: 1
        weight_filler {
            type: "xavier"
            std: 0.01
        }
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 0
        }
    }
}
layer {
    name: "relu1"
    type: "ReLU"
    bottom: "conv1"
    top: "conv1"
}
layer {
    name: "pool1"
    type: "Pooling"
    bottom: "conv1"
    top: "pool1"
    pooling_param {
        pool: MAX
        kernel_size: 2
        stride: 2
    }
}
layer {
    name: "ip1"
    type: "InnerProduct"
    bottom: "pool1"
    top: "ip1"
    param {
        lr_mult: 1
    }
    param {
        lr_mult: 2
    }
    inner_product_param {
        num_output: 8
        weight_filler {
            type: "gaussian"
            std: 0.005
        }
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 0
        }
    }
}
```

The model is trained by myself. Used data size is 70000 * 2 * 64 * 64. 
The network can do nothing but a trial to test why I always get an error like this.

```
I0830 18:49:22.437019 10536 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer data
I0830 18:49:22.437019 10536 net.cpp:91] Creating Layer data
I0830 18:49:22.437019 10536 net.cpp:399] data -> imgPairsSubMean
I0830 18:49:22.437019 10536 net.cpp:399] data -> boundings
I0830 18:49:22.437019 10536 net.cpp:141] Setting up data
I0830 18:49:22.437019 10536 net.cpp:148] Top shape: 1 2 64 64 (8192)
I0830 18:49:22.437019 10536 net.cpp:148] Top shape: 1 (1)
I0830 18:49:22.437019 10536 net.cpp:156] Memory required for data: 32772
I0830 18:49:22.437019 10536 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer conv1
......
I0830 18:49:22.681442 10536 net.cpp:425] ip1 <- pool1
I0830 18:49:22.681442 10536 net.cpp:399] ip1 -> ip1
I0830 18:49:22.681442 10536 net.cpp:141] Setting up ip1
I0830 18:49:22.681442 10536 net.cpp:148] Top shape: 1 8 (8)
I0830 18:49:22.681442 10536 net.cpp:156] Memory required for data: 69668
I0830 18:49:22.681442 10536 net.cpp:219] ip3 does not need backward computation.
I0830 18:49:22.681442 10536 net.cpp:219] pool1 does not need backward computation.
I0830 18:49:22.681442 10536 net.cpp:219] relu1 does not need backward computation.
I0830 18:4***Check failure stack trace***   
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

**Please pay attention to the last two lines**.

I used to think it might be the memory limitation of Pycharm, so I changed the .vmoptions files, no use; I changed the data type from "MemoryData" to "Input", no luck.

So, can anyone give a hint what's going on here? What could I do to get rid of that? Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a stack trace below this?  When I make such errors, I also get a stack trace that often includes a reference to the code that failed.

Comment: Hi @Prune, I've shown all I get from "Caffe" or "Pycharm" (I'm sorry I still have no idea where the problem comes from). Do you have any ideas about this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Ouch!  No, I've never seen it without a stack trace.  Something aborted your *stdout* stream, I see, and that appears to have eaten your stack trace.  Getting this far implies that much of your model structure is correct.  The error code is for a **Stack Buffer Overflow**, but I don't see what's trying to reach beyond the boundaries.  Do you have any "golden" model (one you know is good, and of very similar structure)?  If so, you could start with that and gradually change it to the one you want.  I'd start at the front, just because most human errors involve the input.

Comment: Thank you for providing the information. I tried more and here maybe some more hints: **1**. not loading the caffemodel, I just tried net = caffe.Net(myNet ,  caffe.TEST)  It loads the net perfectly. **2**. I changed to use Spyder, the error information showed the same thing in "**console**" window, but in "**IPython console**" window it provided something new: It **repeatedly** presented "**It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console**". So can those be a help for your brilliant inference? @Prune

Comment: Not brilliant -- just someone who's been making his own mistakes for a few weeks.  :-)  I'm afraid I don't have anything new for you at this point.  I also thought in terms of setting a breakpoint on exception, but I expect that will merely drag you to deep levels inside the code, well below the problem point -- and that the "gentle metamorphosis" method is likely to give you faster results.

Comment: And I don't have a classic model by using MemoryData as input. So if you have any little example that I can learn from you, I'd be truly appreciate that. This is my very first net/model. Everything from scratch. I do meet a lot of problems. Thank you again for your help and understanding.@Prune

Comment: Sorry; the ones I have to give out are the ones that come with Caffe.  We use the models for performance analysis, so we stick with the well-established ones.

Comment: No problem. Because I need a 2-channel "monster" as input, I think I have to build it myself. Never mind. Thank you so much~